# Changing the active database in django

Tags: python, django

i'm writing a testing application that i'm using to test the rest of my code base. What i'd like to be able to do for it is when i test using this manage.py command, automatically change to be logging to a different database. is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django automatically creates and drops a test database for you. Unless otherwise specified (we'll see how to in a second) this will be `test_` + `<the name of the database in the settings file>`. So if your `settings` uses database `foo`, the tests will be executed against `test_foo`. No configuration changes are needed for this.

If you wish to execute tests against a custom database (rather than `test_foo`) you can do that by tweaking the [`TEST_NAME` setting](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEST_NAME). You can add `TEST_NAME` to each dictionary in `DATABASES`.

Comment: I'm not actually running the testing suite. I'm trying to be able to switch between local testing and aws testing.

Answer (score 0):

Create a testing version of `settings.py`, and specify it on the command line when you run your test:

```
$ python manage.py test --settings=settings_test
```

Comment: Do I need to change my manage.py file to reflect this? My application doesn't seem to be prepared to have this as a parameter.

Comment: Nope, you just need to create a new settings file and specify the module name. It's best to have the file `from settings import *` to retain all of your normal settings. See `python manage.py help`.